# Invoking A Method From Another File C#

Tags: c#, methods

I'm having trouble calling my methods. I have 2 separate files. When the user types S then the shake method in my other file will be invoked. So then when the user gets the answer it will be random.

I confused about how to bring that method in another file. Below are both files.

Program.cs:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Main program!");
     Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Magic 8 Ball");
     Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
     Console.WriteLine("(S)hake the Ball");
     Console.WriteLine("(A)sk a Question");
     Console.WriteLine("(G)et the Answer");
     Console.WriteLine("(E)xit the Game");
     Magic8Ball_Logic.Magic8Ball ball = new Magic8Ball_Logic.Magic8Ball();
     string input = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

     public static string userAnswer = "";

     do
     {
        if (input == "S")
        {
            if (userAnswer != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Searching the Mystic Realms(RAM) for the answer");
            }
            else
            {
                //Call Method Shake()
            }
        }
        else if (input == "A") {
                userAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else if (input == "G") {
               //Call Method GetAnswer()
        }
    } while (input != "E");
}
```

Magic8Ball.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Magic8Ball_Logic
{

    public class Magic8Ball
    {
        private List<string> _answers;
        private int _currentIndex;
        private string randomString;

        public Magic8Ball()
        {
            _answers = new List<string>();
            _answers.Add("It is certain.");
            _answers.Add("It is decidedly so.");
            _answers.Add("Without a doubt.");
        }

        public Magic8Ball(List<string> answers)
        {
            //I won't use the 20 default.  use the ones passed in .
            _answers = answers;
        }

        public void Shake()
        {
            //picking the index of the answer to show the user
            Random r = new Random();
            int index = r.Next(_answers.Count);
            randomString = _answers[index];
        }

        public string GetAnswer()
        {
            //using the index picked by shake to return the answer
            //return "";
            return randomString;
        }

        public int AnswerCount
        {
            get { return _answers.Count; }
        }

       /* public override string ToString()
        {
            foreach (var el in _answers)
            {
                return el;
            }
        }*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a full code of Magic8Ball.cs?

Comment: Is the shake method in class Magic8Ball?

Comment: @AndrewPatynko Just added

Comment: Stop think of them as simply files and think in terms of classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was written here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55986849/10128127

Your Program.cs should be updated like:

- replace this comment

*//Call Method Shake()* with

`ball.Shake();`

- replace this comment

*//Call Method GetAnswer()* with

`ball.GetAnswer();`

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must create an object of this class,then invoke the method.

```
   **Edit**
    ball.Shake();
```

Comment: It was created here Console.WriteLine("(E)xit the Game"); Magic8Ball_Logic.Magic8Ball ball = new Magic8Ball_Logic.Magic8Ball(); string input = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();